# In AWS Rekognition, is it possible to list all ongoing FaceDetection jobs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'm running into LimitExceededException when starting new AWS Rekognition jobs with the StartFaceDetection API call, so I would like to see a list of my currently running face detection jobs. The GetFaceDetection command apparently requires you to pass in a specific single job ID, but I would like to see all jobs that are currently in progress (or even all jobs that were started recently). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rekognition API does not have an operation to retrieve all running operations, you would need to handle this on your side. You could use a [RekognitionWaiter](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/rekognition/waiters/RekognitionWaiter.html) to get notifications on the state of individual jobs and keep track in a database of some sort.

Depending on the number of jobs you want to run in parallel and the region you're using right now, you might get a higher limit by using another region. You can check the service quotas for Rekognition [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rekognition.html#limits_rekognition).